# R - recursively create dataframe columns via index inside function

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion, lapply

I have a dataframe with a large amount of annual data.  For example consider the following toy example like so:

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:2, quantity = 3:4, agg_2002 = 5:6, agg_2003 = 7:8, agg_2020 = 9:10)
```

What I would  like to do is the following:

1. Look for columns named "agg_",in the set of column names, `names(df)`
2. Substitute the "agg_" in `names(df)` for "change_"
3. Calculate the relative change from year to year, so for example,

   `df$change_2002 <- df$agg_2002/df$agg_2002` (since 2002 is first year)

   `df$change_2003 <- df$agg_2003/df$agg_2002`

   `df$change_2004 <- df$agg_2004/df$agg_2003`...all the way up to 2020 or the latest value with "agg_" in the column name.

What I have so far is the following function:

```
func <- function(dat, overwrite = FALSE) {
  nms <- grep("agg_[0-9]+$", names(dat), value = TRUE)
  revnms <- gsub("agg_", "chg_", nms)
  for i = 1:ncol(df) %in% revnms{
    dat[, rvnms][i] <- lapply(dat[, rvnms][i], `/`, dat[, rvnms][i-1])
  }
  dat
}
```

What I am struggling with is the indexing.  How do I get R to make the above calculations recursively without having to do it manually?  The desired result is the "chg_" columns appended to the original dataframe:

```
  id quantity agg_2002 agg_2003 agg_2020 chg_2002 chg_2003 chg_2020
1  1        3        5        7        9        1     1.40     1.28
2  2        4        6        8       10        1     1.33     1.25
```

I would like to modify the specified function above to produce the desired result via `lapply` if possible.  All ideas are welcome. Thank you.

**UPDATE:  I would much prefer something using `lapply` or something that can accomodate differing data types**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make table to long form, change name (can use `gsub`), then spread back

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- dat %>% pivot_longer(-c(id,quantity), names_to = "agg", values_to = "year") %>% 
  mutate(agg = str_replace(agg, "agg", "change")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(year = ifelse(is.na(lag(year)), year/year, year/lag(year))) %>% # Divide itself if there is no lag(year)
  pivot_wider(names_from = "agg", values_from = "year") 

inner_join(dat, df, by = c("id","quantity"))

  id quantity agg_2002 agg_2003 agg_2020 change_2002 change_2003 change_2020
1  1        3        5        7        9           1    1.400000    1.285714
2  2        4        6        8       10           1    1.333333    1.250000
```

Comment: this looks good and readable.  question: would this work if i added another "agg_" column to `dat`?  I would like to be able to add "agg_" columns and have it update.  Also, `change_2002` is NA in this solution and not 1

Comment: It should work fine as long as the name is `agg_`.
For the column NA, that is due to there is no previous parameter to divide with. Just mutate that column to 1.

Comment: I've edited the code for your condition by using `ifelse`. Check it out.

Comment: This works on the toy example because all columns are the same.  When I run on my actual data frame containing <double> and <character> vectors, I get the error that I can't combine them.

Comment: I modified it and it worked great.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Always glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("agg"),
                      names_to = "year",
                      names_prefix = "agg_",
                      values_to = "agg") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(change = agg / lag(agg, 1)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = c("agg", "change"))
```